# Form is not bound in Django

Tags: django, htmx

I'm trying to integrate Django with htmx. I want to render a form inside a table. but when I enter some data and submit it says the form is not bound. 
***This is the view:***

```
def hx_payment_item_create(request, payment_id):
    payment = get_object_or_404(Payment, pk=payment_id)
    form = forms.PaymentItemCreateFromPaymentForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            item = form.save(commit=False)
            item.payment = payment
            item.save()
            if request.htmx:
                return redirect("core:hx-payment-item-detail", pk=item.pk)

            return redirect("core:payment-item-detail", pk=item.pk)
        else:
            print(form.errors)
    context = {"form": form, "payment": payment}
    return render(request, "core/partials/payment_item_form.html", context)
```

***This is the template that will be rendered inside the table:***

```
<tr hx-target="this" hx-swap="outerHTML">
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.non_field_errors }}
            {% for hidden_field in form.hidden_fields %}
                {{ hidden_field.errors }}
                {{ hidden_field }}
            {% endfor %}
            {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                <td>
                    <label for="{{ form.subject.id_for_label }}">{{ field.label }}</label>
                        {{ field.errors }}
                        {{ field }}
                        {{ field.help_text }}
                </td>
            {% endfor %}
                <td>
                    <button type="submit" hx-post="#some_url">
                        submit
                    </button>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button hx-get="#another_url" type="button">
                        cancel
                    </button>
                </td>
        </form>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Could you also share your related model and form?

Comment: I guess 'request.POST' is empty. What happens if you remove the 'or None' when creating the form instance?

Comment: I found what was the problem, and it's just about HTML. You can't have a form within a table.